# unable to find valid certification path to requested target Error

Tags: socks, java, certificate

I downloaded the Tor browser, and ran the Tor exe file.
I then run the code shown below to try an access a website using SOCKS

```
    SocketAddress sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost",9050);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS,sockAddr);
    URL url = new URL("https://check.torproject.org/");

    url.openConnection(proxy);

    InputStream in = url.openConnection(proxy).getInputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] stuff = new byte[1024];
    int readBytes = 0;
    while((readBytes = in.read(stuff))>0) {
        bout.write(stuff,0,readBytes);
    }
    byte[] result = bout.toByteArray();
    System.out.print(new String(result));
```

When i run my code i get the following error

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I read that this could be due to an older version of Java so i upgraded Java to 
jdk1.8.0_121

Can anyone help with this error

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem for all certs issued by "[Let's encrypt"](https://letsencrypt.org/). Go there and add their root certificate to your trusted list - it's usually not in case of old distro's, OpenJDK and so forth. Details about their certificate root are [here](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) - grab them and import into your OS trusted certificates store

Comment: You can use `keytool` to import the cert: `keytool -importcert -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias 'Ident Trust X3' -file "$downloaded_root_cert" -keystore "$keystore_path" -storepass changeit`. `$keystore_path` is the location of your keystore. It's usually called `cacerts` but the location differs depending on OS and setup. (Yes, the password is *changeit* by default.)